# Sync Timer Callback in C#

Tags: c#, timer, periodic-processing

I would like to create a function that is called periodically (1 second), the function may take more than 1 second. If the function does not complete, a new thread should not be created. If it completes, it should wait till due time. Which timer method would be the best solution in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Using Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-Main") you can do this:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    .Subscribe(n =>
    {
        /* Do work here */
    });
```

It waits the interval between the subscription calls.

Comment: Wouldn't this run regardless of whether or not another thread has been completed?

Comment: @Rariolu - No, it's not a `Timer`, it's an `Interval`. It waits for the gap between running each subscription.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();//Create new instance of "Timer" class.
timer.Interval = 1000;//Set the interval to 1000 milliseconds (1 second).
bool started = false;//Set the default value of "started" to false;
timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>//Set the procedure that occurs each second.
{
    if (!started)//If the value of "started" is false (if it isn't running in another thread).
    {
        started = true;//Set "started" to true to ensure that this code isn't run in another thread.
        //Other code to be run.
        started = false;//Set "started" to false so that the code can be run in the next thread.
    }
};
timer.Enabled = true;//Start the timer.
```